# Sort map by String values with predicate

Tags: java

I am trying to sort the map by String values with predicted. For example, I have the next values in my map

```
message,
message_message1_message2,
message1_message2,
```

I wanna sort my map by `_` symbols in values String. The result should be like this:

```
message_message1_message2,
message1_message2,
message
```

I am trying this way:

```
        myMap.entrySet().stream().sorted((e1, e2) -> {
            String[] firstCompareValue = e1.getKey().split("_");
            String[] secondCompareValue = e2.getKey().split("_");
            return Integer.compare(firstCompareValue.length, secondCompareValue.length);
        }).collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Function.identity()));
```

and I've got next notification

> Redundant 'sorted' call: subsequent 'toMap' call doesn't depend on
> the sort order

What am I doing wrong? How it can be done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Collectors.toMap()` variant you are using creates a `HashMap` (at least that's the current implementation), so it doesn't preserve the ordering produced by your `Stream`.

If you produce a `LinkedHashMap`, it would be preserved:

```
    myMap.entrySet().stream().sorted((e1, e2) -> {
        String[] firstCompareValue = e1.getKey().split("_");
        String[] secondCompareValue = e2.getKey().split("_");
        return Integer.compare(firstCompareValue.length, secondCompareValue.length);
    }).collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                Function.identity(),
                                (v1,v2)->v1,
                                LinkedHashMap::new));
```

BTW, you are creating a `Map<String,Map.Entry<String,String>>`, which I'm not sure is what you want. If you want a `Map<String,String>` change `Function.identity()` to `Map.Entry::getValue`.